# axis2 1.6.1 migration issue - ListenerManager.defaultConfigurationContext

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, upgrade

I'm currently migrating an axis2 1.5.1 installation to 1.6.1. currentyl I'm facing several issues.

e.g.: where's the

```
ListenerManager.defaultConfigurationContext
```

field gone?
where do I get the current configuration context?
regards

Comment: Take a look at [this table](http://linuxtesting.org/upstream-tracker/java/versions/axis2.html). This may be of help to port your application.

Answer (score 2):

that method is no longer supported. you can use `MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getConfigurationContext()` if you want to access the configuration context at the service.

Comment: in a service context that's true, but what if I want to add services dynamically to the current context? or if I want to offer a custom gui to the configuration context to display all deployed services etc.?

Comment: In that case you can create some Axis2 services (some Admin services) which does that work and client can invoke that Admin service.What is your exact requirement? I think even you can get the configuration context from the servlet context as well.